# How to make a sequence like 1:n, 1:(n-1), ... 1:2, 1?

Tags: r, vector, sequence, seq

`n` is an integer. The sequence I would like is:

```
1:n, 1:(n-1), 1:(n-2), ... , 1:3, 1:2, 1
```

---

**Editor note:**

In R, `1:n-1` is different from `1:(n-1)`. Be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As short as `sequence(n:1)`.

```
sequence(4:1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

---

The function does no mystery (see note at the bottom):

```
function (nvec) 
unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))
```

So [snoram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320899/4891738) reinvents the wheel. But calling `seq_len` is faster than calling other options as it is a primitive function (a C function) with only one argument.

```
sequence2 <- function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq.int, from = 1))
sequence3 <- function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, function(x) 1:x))
sequence4 <- function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq.default, from = 1))
sequence5 <- function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq, from = 1))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sequence(100:1), sequence2(100:1),
               sequence3(100:1), sequence4(100:1), sequence5(100:1))
#Unit: microseconds
#             expr     min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
#  sequence(100:1)  93.292  160.9325  205.5617  173.1995  200.0005 1157.201
# sequence2(100:1) 117.625  226.2120  308.4929  248.1055  280.8625 5477.710
# sequence3(100:1) 126.289  233.7875  365.6455  268.0495  301.8860 8808.911
# sequence4(100:1) 606.301 1195.4795 1463.3400 1237.5580 1344.3145 9986.619
# sequence5(100:1) 944.099 1864.3920 2063.3712 1942.2240 2119.3930 8581.593

## speed comparison
    seq     <  seq.default  <  function(x) 1:x  <  seq.int  <       seq_len
s3 generic       normal      light-weighted user  primitive   1-argument primitive
```

---

**A note on 2022-07-31**

Function `sequence` is now more powerful and more efficient. It no longer has source code as I showed above. I don't know when it was upgraded, though. I can't find relevant description in **R** NEWS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 李哲源's solution won't be improved. But just for curiosity a very generalisable R'ish way would be something like:

```
unlist(lapply(4:1, function(x) 1:x))
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```